# How around function works when we specify negative decimal

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am working with numpy functions. I have applied around function on the array    a = np.array([1.0,5.55,123,0.567,25.532])
This returns following result:
[  0.  10. 120.   0.  30.]
I didn't understand how 2nd element becomes 10?

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) is very clear: ***"If decimals is negative, it specifies the number of positions to the left of the decimal point."***

Comment: @user3483203  I have read documentation but can't understand.Could you explain by giving a simple example

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your full code I can't be sure, but it looks like you're round to `-1` places -- to the 10s place. Consider the following:

```py
for scale in [2,1,0,-1,-2]:
    print(f'round(555.555, {scale})\t= {round(555.555, scale)}')
```

```
round(555.555,  2)  = 555.55
round(555.555,  1)  = 555.6
round(555.555,  0)  = 556.0
round(555.555, -1)  = 560.0
round(555.555, -2)  = 600.0
```

Comment: How 5.55 becomes 10 in third case..please explain

Comment: It's rounding to the nearest 10 -- any `x` where `5.0 <= x < 15`, when rounded to the 10s place, will round to 10.

Comment: An example with more digits might help make it clearer, e.g. `np.round(2345.67, -2)` -> `2300.0`